# Draw line between two plots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to draw a line between points of two plots as shown in the picture (the blue line) but without luck. It is with tikzpicture and pgfplots. Similar to:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot coordinates { (1,2) (2,3) };
  \addplot coordinates { (1,4) (2,6) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I did try adding nodes to \addplot but they seem to be located at (0,0) regardless of settings.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `pgfplots` package introduces a coordinate system that allows you to use diagram coordinates with normal `tikZ` drawing commands by specifying `axis cs:` before your coordinates as in

```
\draw (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:2,0);
```

Below is your code expanded with a line drawn from (2,3) to (2,6):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates { (1,2) (2,3) };
    \addplot coordinates { (1,4) (2,6) };
    \draw (axis cs:2,3) -- node[left]{Text} (axis cs:2,6);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: expanded with a line drawn from (2,3) to (2,6)]

Comment: With pgfplots version 1.11 you can instead `\draw (axis cs:2,3) -- node[left]{Text} (axis cs:2,6);` write `\draw (2,3) -- node[left]{Text} (2,6);`. For this you need to declare `pgfplotsset{compat: 1.13}` in document preamble (if you used the latest version of `pgfplots`).

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the hint. I can't check it myelf right now since I'm still on 1.10 for some legacy task that I have to finish and where I don't want to mess up with things by updating in the middle of the process. But is it really `compat 1.13` if it is a new feature in version 1.11 or is this a typo?

Comment: @BenediktBauer, version 1.11 is not the last, so I in my comment I give example for the last version (since if you will upgrade `pgfplots`, you will get this one). It is worth to upgrade it (as soon as possible).

Comment: @Zarko In general I would absolutely agree, but since am currently still on TexLive2013, upgrading would mean upgrading my whole TeX distribution anyways. With a dissertation that is some hours work away from final publication, I won't take the hassle of everything getting messed up. I have tried compiling it once on a computer with a newer TexLive distribution and it failed terribly.